# How do I determine all complex solutions of $|z|z=-i(\bar{z})$, for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Let $z\in \mathbb{C}$. How do I determine all complex solutions of $|z|z=-i(\bar{z})$?

**My approach:** We can see that $$|x+yi|(x+yi)=y-ix$$ Then I came up with the real part $$-y^2+x^2+x^4-y^4$$ and the imaginary part $$2ixy+x^2(2iyx)+y^2(2xiy)$$

I don't know how to go on and I think that is wrong anyway.I would appreciate every attempt to help!

Comment: What do you denote $z^*$?

Comment: the complex conjugate of z

Comment: This is not the usual notation…

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to do the usual one on the pc

Comment: As in latex: `\bar{z}`.

Comment: You should put your math notation between two dollar signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|z|=1$, then $\overline{z} = 1/z$ and the equation becomes
$$
z = -i/z,
\\
z^2 = -i
$$
with two solutions
$$
z = \frac{-1+i}{\sqrt{2}},\qquad z=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Comment: How do I get $\bar{z} = 1/z$?

Comment: $z\bar z=|z|^2$

Answer (score 2):

Beside $z=0$, polar form gives $r^2e^{i\theta}=re^{-i(\theta+\pi/2)}$ so $r^2=r\implies r=1$, and $2\theta+\pi/2=2n\pi$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$, i.e. $\theta=-\pi/4+n\pi$. There are two nonzero solutions, $\pm e^{-\pi i/4}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

If $|z|\, z=-i\bar z$, the moduli of both sides are the same, so $|z|^2=|z|$, which implies that $|z|=0$ (so $z=0$) or $|z|=1$.

For the latter case, the  best is to use the exponential form: $z=\mathrm e^{i\theta}$. The equation can be rewritten, since the modulus is $1$, as
$$\mathrm e^{i\theta}=-i\mathrm e^{-i\theta}=\mathrm e^{-i\bigl(\theta+\tfrac\pi 2\bigr)}.$$
Can you take  it from there?

Comment: Is there a way without using the exponential form?

Comment: I didn't t really try to find one, as the exponential is clearly the simplest way yto go here. Do you have problems using it?

Comment: Yes, I never really heard of it because it wasn't introduced in my course

Comment: It's simply a useful way of writing the trigonometric form (based on De Moivre's formula).